# Problematic links in a locked answer

Tags: support, editing

[This answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/43671/9546) to a locked question of historical significance contains links (plural) to www.londonelegance.com. Upon clicking one of the links I was asked to upgrade my Java although it looked more like a malware attempt than a genuine prompt. On a second click I was presented with a domain for sale page. Either way, the links are dead.

I cannot edit or flag the answer as it is locked. Could a moderator please remove these links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your wish is my command :-) Thanks for bringing it up - I will try to propose locked posts to be flaggable on the main StackExchange Meta.

Comment: Thank you Jonathan. It doesn't _appear_ to be possible to flag historical locked posts _at all_ i.e. I couldn't even flag the question. Ctrl-f flag finds nothing on the entire page.

Comment: @JonathanReez Yes, that's the whole point. You *can't* flag anything on a locked post.

Comment: @choster bummer. Post updated.

Comment: Actually, it's intentional that historically-locked posts should not be flaggable; see [this MSE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247501/allow-flags-on-locked-posts). Posting a request here on meta is actually the correct process to follow.